# Logging variable's javadoc

Tags: java, android, exception, javadoc, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics with my Android app. I'd like to log exceptions with descriptive messages.

One idea of mine is when starting an activity, if there is an error that results in the code finishing the activity is to set the result to "RESULT_ERROR" and then add data to the intent with an error code. In onActivityResult I'm logging an exception with

```
int error_code = data.getIntExtra(Const.KEY_ERROR_CODE, Const.ERROR_UNKNOWN);
Crashlytics.logException(new Exception(Integer.toString(error_code)));
```

I would like the string I'm logging to also contain a description of the error_code. I already describe the error code in the javadoc for the variable, so is there a way to retrieve the javadoc for a variable as a String?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Not trivially, no. It would make a *lot* more sense to simply add an exception message like everyone in the world does it.

Comment: That is what I want to do.. since the error code javadocs are descriptions of the errors I thought i could recycle some text. If it's not trivial though, I won't bother trying.

Comment: You could write a javadoclet that puts (something) into a property/resource file, I suppose, but meh. Exception messages should be concise, complete, and actionable. I keep them explicitly separate from JavaDocs, which IMO serve a different purpose. Also, exception messages should contain info about the state causing the exception, which isn't really possible in a static doc.